# have character move based off of camera axis with joystick [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gamepad

I have recently began practicing with Unity3D and created a sort of camera which slowly Lerps behind the player facing the direction they are going. My intention is to have the players movement based off the direction the camera is facing as opposed to the characters movement being based entirely off world space.

If any one can help me out as to how I would go about having the characters movement based off camera axis as opposed to world axis is would be much appreciated.

Character movement script

```
 if (gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterJumpScript>().isGrounded)
        {
            Vector3 posi = new Vector3((Input.GetAxis("LeftJoystickHorizontal") * characterMovement), 0.0f, (Input.GetAxis("LeftJoystickVertical") * characterMovement));
            this.transform.position += posi;
        }
```

camera follow script

```
 private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float rot = followTarget.gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        print(rot);
        Vector3 oldOffset = cameraOffset;
        cameraOffset = Vector3.Lerp(oldOffset, new Vector3(-Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * rot) * 20.0f, 8.0f, -Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * rot) * 20.0f), Time.deltaTime);
        Vector3 desiredPosition = followTarget.position + cameraOffset;
        Vector3 smoothPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position = smoothPosition ;
        transform.LookAt(followTarget);
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm curious- if your camera is meant to rotate based on the character's moving direction, AND the character moves in the direction that the camera is facing... how will you move in any direction but straight forward? It's possibly I may be misunderstanding part of your question.

Comment: the camera moves to be facing the direction the character is facing, it will always be looking at the players back